# How to take a part from a list without evaluating it

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, expression-manipulation, hold

Consider I have a list l

```
l = {
  b + Integrate[Sin[t*q], {t, 0, 1.1}]^2 == b + Integrate[Cos[t*q], {t, 0, 1.1}]
, a + Integrate[Sin[t*p], {t, 0, 1.1}]^2 ==  b + Integrate[Cos[t*q], {t, 0, 1.1}]
}
```

Now I want another function to take just take one part of the expression without evaluating it. How do I do it? Basically I want something along the lines of

```
ExtractUnevaluated[l, 1]
```

With result

```
b + Integrate[Sin[t*q], {t, 0, 1.1}]^2 == b + Integrate[Cos[t*q], {t, 0, 1.1}]
```

How do I do this? Specificically how do I define `ExtractUnevalued[l_List,n_]:= ???`?

To be a bit clearer I want to pass the part of the list to a function defined by:

```
SetAttributes[DiscretizeIntegralOnSet,HoldFirst]

DiscretizeIntegralOnSet[ Integrate[A_,{t_,tmin_,tmax_}], discretpointlist_
]:=some stuff(not relevant)

DiscretizeIntegralOnSet[ A_+B_, discretpointlist_
]:=some other stuff(not relevant)
```

That then allows me to symbolically write a discretized integral as sum over a set.

Comment: If `l` is not already evaluated you can use `Inactivate` as follows: `l2 =Inactivate[{b + Integrate[Sin[t*q], {t, 0, 1.1}]^2 == 
   b + Integrate[Cos[t*q], {t, 0, 1.1}], 
  a + Integrate[Sin[t*p], {t, 0, 1.1}]^2 == 
   b + Integrate[Cos[t*q], {t, 0, 1.1}]}, Integrate]; l2[[2]]`

Comment: See also this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160700/efficient-way-to-get-elements-in-list

Comment: If you're going to pass it into another function, `Extract[list, pos, Unevaluated]` should do the trick. However, you need to make sure the list doesn't evaluate when you define it (by using `Hold` instead of `List`, for example).

Comment: Regrettably this does not work either because I am stuck with a hold that remains

Comment: That's why you have to use `Unevaluated` when extracting the elements from the held list.

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `DiscretizeIntegralOnSet` is fixed and you don't want /it is not possible to add any syntactic sugar, you can do this:

```
l = Hold @ {..., ...};

l[[ {1}, n ]] /. Hold[x_]:> DiscretizeIntegralOnSet[x, whatever]
```

or

```
Function[
  x, DiscretizeIntegralOnSet[x, whatever], HoldFirst
] @@ l[[{1}, n]]
```

Regarding the first method you may reference:

- [Injecting a sequence of expressions into a held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1929/)
- [Head and everything except Head?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2449/)

Comment: I hope you don't mind my edit; I think it's needed to understand what's going on there if you area not already quite familiar with *Mathematica*.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Indeed, I was planning to, the first day since posting is for updates :) Thanks for edits.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it: you store the equations in `Hold` to prevent evaluation and then use `Extract` to get the elements out unevaluated:

```
l = Hold[
  b + Integrate[Sin[t*q], {t, 0, 1.1}]^2 == b + Integrate[Cos[t*q], {t, 0, 1.1}], 
  a + Integrate[Sin[t*p], {t, 0, 1.1}]^2 == b + Integrate[Cos[t*q], {t, 0, 1.1}]
]


ClearAll[DiscretizeIntegralOnSet]
DiscretizeIntegralOnSet[i : Integrate[A_, {t_, tmin_, tmax_}], discretpointlist_] := 
  Hold[i, A, t, tmin, tmax];


With[{int = Extract[l, {1, 1, 2, 1}, Unevaluated]}, 
 DiscretizeIntegralOnSet[int, points]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SetAttributes[ExtractUnevaluated, HoldFirst]
ExtractUnevaluated[l_List, n_] :=  ReleaseHold[Map[Hold, Hold@l, {2}]][[n]]
```

Comment: The hold that remains makes it regrettably not what I wanted